# Why does the Startup Object in Visual Studio only pickup Main() without arguments?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Why is it that the Startup  Object under Project properties for a solution will only recognize files with a Main() method without any parameters?

For example:

```
public static void Main()
```

is fine

whereas

```
public static void Main(String[] Args)
```

will not be picked up by the Visual Studio as a valid Startup Object?

Comment: I believe it depends on your project type.  A console application only accepts `string[] args`

Comment: How do i know which project type accepts which types of arguments or any?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a console app is the only one that accepts arguments, because it's the only one that can.  How would you pass an argument to a WPF app?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is wrong in it's premise that you cannot do this.  A console application will let you pass arguments in exactly that way:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

However, for a WPF app, you can choose a start-up object, or allow the object to be specified in the `app.config`.  Consequently, there is no place for start-up parameters.

Comment: +1. Addendum: that's why you have to read them overriding `OnStartup(StartupEventArgs)` method from `Application` (well...ok or from `Environment.GetCommandLineArguments()`)

Comment: I understand that a console application will let me pass arguments in that way, but in Visual Studio, I am not able to choose it as a valid Startup Object because it has Main(string[] args). However, when I change it to Main(), Visual Studio will allow me to choose the file as a startup Object. Is there a reason this is happening?

Comment: When you say `choose it as a valid Startup Object`, do you mean that you have more than one project in a solution, and want to select the console app to start, or that you're somehow trying to set a class that doesn't contain a static main function as the startup?